# Does there exist a topological group which can be covered by a collection of open abelian subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups

I recently [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2245010/does-there-exist-a-topological-group-where-every-point-has-a-nontrivial-neighb/2245245#2245245) about the existence of topological groups which can be covered by a collection of open subgroups. It turns out that there do exist topological groups with this property. Now I want to know if there exists a topological group which can be covered by a collection of open **abelian** subgroups. Obviously every abelian topological group has this property, but what about nonabelian groups? If such a group has this property, then we can think of it as being "locally abelian" (note that in group theory, this has a different meaning). This might seem like a useful property for a topological group. Have the topological groups with this property been classified.

Comment: If there is an open abelian subgroup, the component of the identity is abelian. Factoring that out, you have a discrete group, and every group is the union of its cyclic subgroups. So take any old non-abelian group, endow it with the discrete topology, and you're there. If you want something non-discrete, take a direct product with a connected abelian group.